# Buddybuild auto deploy errors with `Missing required parameters: packageName`

Tags: android, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, buddy-build

When attempting to deploy my Android app to the google play store and there are no variants to choose from to manually deploy the app either. The docs don't mention anything about `packageName`.

All the tests pass and it also builds successfully.

Comment: Have you uploaded your app to the Google Play Store manually ?

Comment: Yeah I've uploaded my app to the store on production